# Pyspark, How to add a new existing column

Tags: python, pyspark

So let's say I have a dataset like this:

```
Y     M     D
2017  3     4
2017  2     5
```

And a single columns dataset created when I fused the first dataset like this:

```
Y:M:D
2017:3:4
2017:2:5
```

How would I join them together now into something like this, with a new column name:

```
Y     M     D   Date
2017  3     4   2017:3:4
2017  2     5   2017:2:5
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I was making a wrong usage of a function and that's why it wasn't working.
Here's the solution:
Being D1 the first dataset:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat,lit
D1 = flights_df.withColumn('Date', 
                concat(col("Y"), lit(":"), col("M"),lit(":"),col("D")))
```